Calculating percentage to display on Card with respect to filters in place in Power BI
I am trying to display a percentage on Card in Power BI. In my data there is a column called "Email" - using that I am calculating distinct count as "Total Values", which is 700.
Then I am adding another card in which there is the same Total Values but there is a  filter, which is another column "Required", which has values "Yes" and "No" (for this i am selecting "Yes"). Then there is another value which is Certification, which has a value of A, B, C, and D. and I am selecting Certification filter with A selected - which then shows as 400. So basically I have two card values, one shows 700 and other shows 400. But on third card value I need their percentage i.e. (400/700)*100
So, to summarize, I wanted to display the percentage displayed in Card A and Card B.
So far I have been trying to use Quick Measure but cannot figure out how to use, as I am not that well versed with it.
Any suggestions would be appreciated.
Thanks,
Mahesh

Can you provide some data?

This is the sample data I used for testing.



Email
Certificatoin




a
A


b
B


c
B


d
C


e
C


f
C


g
D


h
D


i
D


j
D



then you create three measures
MEASURE =
CALCULATE ( DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'Table'[Email] ), ALL ( 'Table' ) )

Measure 2 = DISTINCTCOUNT('Table'[Email])

Measure 3 = DIVIDE([Measure 2],[Measure])


